# Preencher formulários web com o textbox

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou tentando importar informações de um textbox para preenchimento automático de formulários em um site, mas o visual studio 2013 sempre retorna o erro:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in teste.exe"

"Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Exemplo:

```
    Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Commandbutton1.Click

    Dim Procurar As String

    Procurar = Me.textbox1.Text

    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")

    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").InnerText = Procurar
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All("btnK").InvokeMember("Submit")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o link http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=teste.

Altere a palavra *teste* pela palavra que você deseja completar. Esse link vai retornar um arquivo XML com as palavras completadas.